Show the function is bounded

Let $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ have second derivative such that $$ f(x) + f'(x) + f''(x) = 0$$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$. Prove $f$ is bounded.


I tried solving differential equation to get $f$ but didn't work. Also $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x f(x)}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x (f(x)+f'(x))}{e^x}= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x(-f''(x))}{e^x}= \lim_{x \to \infty} -f''(x)$$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Solving the equation does give the answer immediately. Tell us where you got stuck?

@geetha290krm I tried linear differential equation, wrote the expression as $f'(x)+f(x)=-f''(x)$, took $f(x)=y$, then got the integration factor to be $e^x$, but solving for $y$, I got $y=e^{-x} \times [ \int e^x f''(x)+c] , how to proceed?

The solution is $ae^{-\frac 1 2 x}\cos (\frac {\sqrt 3 x}2)+be^{-\frac 1 2 x}\sin (\frac {\sqrt 3 x}2)$

@geetha290krm can you please show how you got it? I have little to no experience solving differential equations

You should read about Homogeneous equation with constant coefficients here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation

You don't need an integrating factor.  I'm not aware of integrating factors applying to 2nd degree equations.  This is a linear ODE with constant coefficients.  Try $y=e^r$, $y'=re^r$, $y''=r^2e^r$, with $r$ as an unknown constant.  Substitute, $y, y' \&\  y''$ into your original ODE, then use Precalculus and Algebra II methods to find r.  You should discover $r$ is a complex number, $a\pm bi$.  When $r=a\pm bi$, the solutions take the form $$y =  e^a(c_1\cos bx + c_2 \sin bx)$$
Note: my a & b are totally different and $\neq$ a or b in geethak290krm's comment.  Specifically, my $c_1 = $ geethak290krm's a and my $c_2 =$ geethak290krm's b.
Once you know the number for my $a$, you'll be able to find the limit.
